# Цикл foreach внутри sql запроса

Tags: php

Здравствуйте пишу функцию для работы с базой данных возник вопрос ,на который пока не нашел решение.
Как значение из цикла поместить в запросю
Вот пример моего кода

```
    foreach($fields as $value) : print_r($value); endforeach;
    $sql ="INSERT INTO ".$table_name." ("..") VALUES ('".$values['0']."','".$values['1']."','".$values['2']."')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно в духе такого:

```
/*
$columns = array("foo", "bar");
$values = array("value foo", "value bar");
*/

assert(count($columns) == count($values));
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)",
               $table_name,
               implode(", ", $columns),
               implode(", ", array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $values));
```

Если надо делать вставку на много рядов, то вариация:

```
$sql_t = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)",
                 $table_name,
                 implode(", ", $columns),
                 substr(str_repeat("%s,", count($columns)), 0, -1));

for ($all_values as $values) {
    $r = mysql_query(vsprintf($sql_t, array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $values)));
    ...
}
```

Но это некромантия. Лучше использовать PDO, в духе

```
 $q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO foo (bar, baz) VALUES (:bar, :baz)");
 $q->execute($values); // $values = array("bar" => ..., "baz" => ...);
```

Для нескольких рядов повторяем вызов `$q->execute()`.

Если запросов много однотипных — то же самое, только prepared statements формировать динамически. Очень грубый набросок:

```
  /* $tables = array(
      "foos" => array("foo", "bar", "baz"),
      "eggs" => array("spam", "ham"),
  ); */
  function prepend_colon($x) { return ":" . $x; }
  foreach($tables as $t => $c) {
      $q[$t] = $db->prepare(sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)", $t,
                                    implode(",", $c),
                                    implode(",", array_map("prepend_colon", $c))));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Запрос поместить в тело цикла наверное, если я правильно понял:

```
foreach ($fileds as $value) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (vlaue1, value2, value3) VALUES ('".$value[0]."', '".$value[1]."', '".$value[2]."')";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Как-то так, а вообще вопрос задан расплывчато.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй такое:

```
foreach($fields as $value) : 
 $value.=", ";
 if (count($value)>0)
  for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++)
   $text.="'{$value["$i"]}'";

endforeach;

$sql ="INSERT INTO ".$table_name." ("..") VALUES ( $text );";
```

---

Как вариант, если я тебя правильно понял.